# How to debug "IO Error: End of TNS data channel" errors?

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g

I am seeing sporadic reports of an application failing certain queries with an "End of TNS data channel" error from the Oracle (10g) server.  Are there any queries I can run (e.g., with SQL*Plus or other tool) to ask the Oracle server what was the cause of such failures?  What logs should I look for?

Comment: What is the error number?

Comment: You mean an ORA-nnnn? There isn't one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could check the alert log, as described in the Stack Overflow Q & A:

[How to find and tail the Oracle alert log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171868/how-to-find-and-tail-the-oracle-alert-log)

...where the question author [tardate](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6329/tardate) says:

> I posted some bash and Perl scripts to find and tail the alert log [on my blog](http://tardate.blogspot.com/2007/04/find-and-tail-oracle-alert-log.html) some time back, and I'm surprised to see that post still getting lots of hits.
>   The technique used is to lookup `background_dump_dest` from `v$parameter`.

The accepted answer by [cagcowboy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19629/cagcowboy) adds:

> If the `background_dump_dest` parameter isn't set, the `alert.log` will be put in `$ORACLE_HOME/RDBMS/trace`.

Answer (score 2):

You will probably need to [get in touch with Oracle support](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:4453916111916383%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:369618129598). Making sure you have the latest patch set applied for your version may help - or finding the exact SQL executing when the server process crashed and working around the Oracle bug causing the crash is often possible.